# How to send function(s) name without qoutes from PHP to JavaScript as JSON object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP array like this one shown below:

```
$value['ranges'] = array(
      array('start' => "moment().startOf()",
              'end'  => "moment().endOf().add(7,'d')"),
      array(
        'start' =>  "moment('2015-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD')",
        'end'=>"moment('2015-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('month')")
             );
```

I want to get the result in JavaScript like the one below:

```
var repeatingEvents = [{
                  ranges: [{ 
                 start: moment().startOf('week'), //next two weeks
                 end: moment().endOf('week').add(7,'d'),
                 },{
                 start: moment('2015-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 
                 end: moment('2015-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('month'),
                  }/*...*/],
                 }/*...*/];
```

Actually I don't need the double quotes around the function names in JavaScript. This is what I get in JavaScript:

```
end: "moment('2015-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('month')"
```

If I remove the double quotes in the PHP array, the **moment** function gets called giving an error. Do you have any idea how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Trying to do what you want could be potentially dangerous. I would advise that your JSON just passes a bunch of flags and your javascript uses if statements to check if a flag exists and runs the required function.

Comment: You can try to `var repeatingEvents = [{ ranges: [{  start: <?php echo $value["ranges"][0]["start"];?> ...`

Comment: I have more than one items , for simplicity I have post one , to do so I will have to iterate over the the Json object and echo the values where required, can we have a smart solution, besides this one? I mean we settle the problem on the php side and only send the JSON object to Js!

Comment: JSON does not allow this.